# How do you permanently stop a particular podcast episode downloading in iTunes?

Tags: itunes, podcasts

Every time I fire up iTunes and it automatically starts to get the lastest podcasts from my subscriptions, there are always some episodes that I don't want to get which happen to be the latest ones from a couple of rarely-updated podcasts. On the Downloads page I find the podcast I don't want and pause it, then delete that row from the list.

The trouble is, I have to keep doing that every time iTunes syncs, until that episode is no longer the latest from that podcast. I can't work out how to permanently register my disinterest in receiving that episode.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the problem? Is an old show trying to get downloaded or a new show you don't want?

I have a few ideas. One would be to delete that episode from the podcast page. Expand that podcast and delete out anything you don't want.

Another option would be to unsubscribe. If doesn't remove it from your list, it just won't check for new shows.

Of like @caliban said, switch those feeds to a manual update. There is a settings link on the bottom. Choose your show from the dropdown list and change the settings to manual updates.

Comment: The problem is I want to ignore the latest episode of a particular podcast. I don't see the option to delete it on the podcasts page if I right-click the episode. I don't want to switch to manual mode for that podcast, I just want it to skip the one I'm not interested in and not have to keep telling it that every time!

Comment: I must be blind - I never noticed that you could right-click Delete (or just 'Delete' button) the individual episode, as you suggested. Tried it, and it worked. Thanks

Comment: Glad to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

You can manage subscription settings for individual podcasts in iTunes 9 (can't remember for earlier versions).

Go to your Podcasts section, click on Settings, and in the "Settings For:" drop down menu, you should be able to choose individual podcasts and change subscription settings for them.

[image]

Comment: The options in that dialogue apply only to the podcast in general. I need the option to skip a single episode on an ad hoc basis, and have it remember that, without having to do it each time. You would think it would appear in the context menu of the item either on the Podcasts page or the Download page.